# How do I change default user settings in RDS Session Host?

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop-services, rds

Using Windows Server 2022...

When a user connects the first time to my RDS Session Host, they get this layout...

[image]

How can I by default remove "server programs", prevent all users (but admins) to access eg. server manager? Get the desktop experience?

Is that controlled by GPO?

I don't want to log in as the user for the first time and manually set up all above.

I need a hint in the right direction :)

Comment: I'd suggest if a non-admin user is connecting to an RDS server via RDP and getting that page, it's because you haven't configured the RDS server yet and you need to look at guides for how to configure a session host... there's a LOT more to it than just installing the role.